# Can't you vs Don't you

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there a difference between "can't you" and "don't you"? As in:

> You just can't behave properly, can't you?

vs.

> You just can't behave properly, don't you?

I don't understand their difference (if there is).

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are wrong.  The second is more wrong.

> You just can't behave properly, can't you?

This should be

> You just can't behave properly, can you?

The second makes no sense at all.

The first sentence, as I've rewritten it, would come across as a criticism and the question at the end would be rhetorical.